# Elasticsearch search result relevance issue

Tags: elasticsearch, search, match

Why does match query return less relevant results first? I have an index field named `normalized`. Its mapping is:

```
normalized: {
    type: "text"
    analyzer: "autocomplete"
}
```

settings for this field are:

```
analysis; {
    filter: {
        autocomplete_filter: {
            type: "edge_ngram",
            min_gram => "1",
            max_gram => "20"
        }
    analyzer: {
        autocomplete: {
            filter: [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "autocomplete_filter"
            ],
            type: "custom",
            tokenizer: "standard"
        }
    }
```

so as I know it makes an ascii, lowercase, tokens e.g. MOUSE = m, mo, mou, mous, mouse.
The problem is that request like:

```
{
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': {
                'match': {
                    'normalized': 'simag'
                }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

returns results like

1. "siman siman service"
2. "mgr simona simunkova simiki"
3. "Siman - SIMANS"
4. "simunek simunek a simunek"
5. .....

But there is no **SIMAG** which contains **all the letters** of the match phrase.
How to achieve that most relevant result will be the words which contains all the letters before the tokens which does not contain all letters.
Hope somebody understand what I need.
Thanks.

PS: I am not sure but what about this query:

```
{
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'should': [
                {'term': {'normalized': 'simag'}},
                {'match': {'normalized': 'simag'}}
             ]
         }
     }
 }
```

Does it make sense in comparison to previous code?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that match query is analyzed, which means the same analyzer is used at the query time, which was used at the index time for the field you mentioned in your query.

In your case, you applied `autocomplete` analyzer on your `normalized` field and as you mentioned, it generates below token for  `MOUSE` :

`MOUSE = m, mo, mou, mous, mouse.`

In similar way, if you search for `mouse` using the `match` query on the same field, it would search for below query strings :-

`m, mo, mou, mous, mouse` .. hence results which contain the words like `mousee` or `mouser` will also come as during index .. it created tokens which matches with the tokens generated on the search term.

Read more about match query on Elastic site https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html first line itself explains your search results

> match queries accept text/numerics/dates, analyzes them, and
> constructs a query:

**If you want to go deep and understand, how your search query is matching the documents and its score use `explain` API**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html

Comment: I understand it. But how to achieve the engine will prefer the results which contains  all letters in the word. What about my last example? Does not term query increase the relevance in combination with match query?

Comment: @Čamo, what are your exact requirements? Is it autocomplete search for search suggestions or for full-text search.. Please list your requirements clearly and then I can provide you suggestions

Comment: It is fulltext not autocomplete. But this fulltext should return most relevant names of companies from database. So if I write SIMAG and there is company with name SIMAG it should return SIMAG at first not SIMA SIMA and so... SIMA should be at the end of the result.

Comment: @Čamo , then why you are using the autocomplete analyzer for your use case.. simply use standard analyzer and just make a match query .. although in this case it won't give the result for SIMA.. if you want that too also come in your result .. then only option is get result from ES and then check which result contains the exact `query string` and show it on top .. But I would avoid doing so and in this case ideally you shouldn't show the result with contains just `SIMA` but yeah using prefix query.. you can make it to show `SIMAGAG`.. `SIMAGINA` etc

Comment: No I want SIMA in result but SIMAG at first. The same question. What about the last  solution in my question? Did you see that? It seems it works.

Comment: @Čamo , yeah I saw that but in this case you are making 2 queries which would have a performance impact.. is this solution you figured out or is it mentioned in some official documents ?

Comment: No this solution is my own. Any documentation for it. Do you think the performance impact would be worse in compare to another much more complicated queries for Elasticsearch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191636/discussion-between-amit-khandelwal-and-camo).